# Pass Session Variable to another page Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

I guys, I'm creating a VB.NET application, and this is the first time that I used Session Variables.

What I want to do is to pass the session variable from a page (**first.aspx**) to another page (**second.aspx**) via url.

Here an example of what I want to do:

In the **first.aspx.vb** page I declare a session variable and assign to it a value

```
Session("example") = "example123"
```

Then I pass this Session Variable to the **first.aspx** page

```
Response.Write(Session("example"))
```

and via javascript read the value of the Variable

```
<script type= text/javascript>
    var SessionVar = '<%=Session("example")%>)';
</script>
```

Now, what I want to do is to change the value of the Variable (for example setting it as `example456`), and then pass the variable to the **second.aspx** [for example with `window.open()`] so that the url not contains the value of the variable but its name:

`url/second.aspx?value=example` **AND NOT** `url/second.aspx?value=example456`

Infact I don't want that the user read the value of the variable.

Finally I have to read the value of the session variable in the **second.aspx.vb** via `Request.QueryString("value")` and do the various operations.

Is it possible ?

If not, there is anothe way to do this

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set session variable from javascript can be done like below:

1. Create a hidden field control on the first page

   ```
   <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
   ```
2. Client script to set value of the hidden field

   ```
   function setVal(value) {
       // if using jQuery
       $("#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>").val(value);

       // if using javascript
       var hf = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>");
       hf.value = value;
   }
   ```
3. Create a button or link to navigate to the second page

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go to second page" OnClick="NavigateToSecondPage" /> 
         or 
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="NavigateToSecondPage">Go to second page</asp:LinkButton>
   ```
4. In the first page code behind, create the `NavigateToSecondPage` sub to handle the onclick event of the button/link

   ```
   Protected Sub NavigateToSecondPage(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       Session("example") = HiddenField1.Value
       Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx")
   End Sub
   ```

Therefore, in your second page, you can access the Session("example") value and it will have a new value set by the client script in the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Session variables are called this way because they are **passed automatically from one page to the other within the same session**, so you should just modify the value of the variable whenever you want and then access it again in the second page to find the value. You don't need to pass anything explicitely.

Comment: So, if i change the value of the variable in a page, this new value will be read from all the other page in which I used the variable ?

Comment: Yes, if you've implemented your sessions right. Check out on Google, there's a lot of material on how to do this.

Comment: ok, but what i dont'understand is how can i set the value of the session variable with the value of a Javascript's variable. Thanks again

Comment: you can assign the js value to a hidden field, than in code behind, retrieve the hidden field value and assign it to a session variable.

Comment: How can i assign a value to a hidden field ? However what i have to do is to change the value of the session variable in the first page (by using javascript) and then to read this value in the second page for doing the various operations.